# Path to Riemann Surfaces and Complex Geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Right now I'm looking at finding a textbook on complex analysis that will be sufficient enough to prepare me for Riemann Surfaces and Complex Geometry. I'm currently looking at Zill's "A First Course in Complex Analysis", Joseph Bak's "Complex Analysis", Gamelin's "Complex Analysis" and Jerrold Marsden's "Basic Complex Analysis" and lastly Ravi Agarwal's "An Introduction to Complex Analysis". Which one of these texts or perhaps others will be very good and cover the right amount of material.

At the moment I'm looking at Ravi Agarwal's "An Introduction to Complex Analysis", and Jerrold Marsden's "Basic Complex Analysis".

Also what important concepts should I understand well enough to start studying Riemann Surfaces and Complex Geometry?

Comment: [Possibly useful roadmap/mindmap of complex analysis](https://www.konradvoelkel.com/2011/11/complex-analysis-mindmap/).

Comment: Important concepts/theorems are : monodromy, analytic continuation (aka identity principle), Mittag-Leffler theorem, branched covering.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the following text for free. I found it very well written for the beginners.

A first course in Complex Analysis Version 1.53 by Matthias Beck, Gerald Marchesi, Dennis Pixton, Lucas Sabalka.

The book is available at the website

http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/complex.html